# Trying to display SMS_Client methods for SCCM using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, sccm

This is the script I have in Powershell;

```
$wmi = get-wmiobject -Namespace root\ccm -class sms_client -list | gm
```

The line above works exactly how I want.

The line below gives me completely different results because I removed the `-list` switch:

```
$wmi = get-wmiobject -Namespace root\ccm -class sms_client | gm
```

My question is how can I transpose the first command to VBScript. I want to be able to call the "TriggerSchedule" method.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (schedule ID taken from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc146704.aspx)):

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/ccm")

scheduleID = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}"

For Each client In wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM SMS_Client")
  client.TriggerSchedule(scheduleID)
Next
```

Untested, though, because I don't have SCCM at hand here.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but try this in PowerShell:

```
GWMI CCM_Scheduler_ScheduledMessage -namespace root\ccm\policy\machine\actualconfig | 
 select-object ScheduledMessageID, TargetEndPoint | 
 where-object {$_.TargetEndPoint -ne "direct:execmgr"}
```

Returns the following, pay attention to the values which are similar to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000116

```
ScheduledMessageID                              TargetEndPoint
------------------                              --------------
{F83F662D-3DE6-4696-B064-701B2D86DADA}          direct:UpdatesDeploymentAgent
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000116}          direct:StateMessageManager
```